# Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Xtreme Audio CA0106 Drivers

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

How do I reinstall my audio drivers?

Mr google tells me I need snd-ca0106 which seems to be missing. Along with all the other audio drivers.

Ubuntu 16.04

```
aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...

sudo alsa force-reload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).

lspci | grep -i Audio
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri HDMI/DP Audio Controller
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
03:06.0 Multimedia audio controller: Creative Labs CA0106 Soundblaster
```

Comment: Does `sudo modinfo snd-ca0106` work? Did you ever manually install any sound drivers?

Comment: No I have only updating alsa using these instructions https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS Then I followed the uninstall instructions when it didn't work. Now I have reinstalled it once more and the normal drivers have returned. but snd-ca0106 is not part of the normal drivers it seems. So I guess the question is - where would I download snd-ca0106?

sudo modinfo snd-ca0106
modinfo: ERROR: Module snd-ca0106 not found.

Comment: Sound drivers are part of the kernel; reinstall the linux kernel package (`linux`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that was a bit of a mission and the main problem is faulty hardware. The reason I installed the sound blaster is because the onboard audio is faulty. There is another fault somewhere that is forcing me to slowly lower the cpu/nb frequency year after year to maintain stability. I have cleaned out the heatsink and re-applied the thermal paste which  didn't make a noticeable difference. I'm down to 1400Mhz now and stock is 1800Mhz. Anyway I found that when the cpu/nb is set unstably high, the sound blaster will usually show up on its own after a cold boot. If the cpu/nb frequency is set down to 1400Mhz (where i get no memory errors), the sound blaster would not show up no mater what I did. So i swapped it into the bottom pci slot and it worked.. well sort of. It was working down the left speakers only. I managed to sort this by setting the volume with 'alsamixer' in terminal. At first this didn't help because the speakers appeared to have volume already. But then I discovered each bar has two halfs, just hold the up arrow on all of them and the right speaker will be turned up. Now it's working. Although running 2400Mhz memory with a 1400Mhz cpu/nb is a bit of a waste but that's another story.